# Windows Driver build - incorrect path passed to Inf2Cat.exe

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, driver, driver-signing

I'm new to the subject of windows drivers. I'm trying to build one of the [Windows-driver-samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples) in Visual Studio 2015. The compilation and linking steps pass without errors and then I get the following error:

```
TRACKER : error TRK0002: Failed to execute command:
    ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\inf2cat.exe"
        /os:10_x64 /driver:x64\Debug\WFPSamplerCalloutDriver\".
The operation identifier is not valid.
```

(Note the relative path in /driver argument). If I call Inf2Cat manually from command prompt with full path to the driver, it passes without a hitch:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86>Inf2Cat.exe /os:10_x64
/driver:C:\Users\****\Windows-driver-samples\network\trans\WFPSampler\sys\x64\Debug\W
FPSamplerCalloutDriver
...........................
Signability test complete.

Errors:
None

Warnings:
None

Catalog generation complete.
C:\Users\****\Windows-driver-samples\network\trans\WFPSampler\sys\x64\Debug
\WFPSamplerCalloutDriver\wfpsamplercalloutdriver.cat
```

So, it seems to me that VS somehow failed to provide the full path to the driver in the argument to Inf2Cat.

How can I fix this? Which configuration property of my project is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

#### Description

Seems Inf2Cat from SDK10 does not accept directory path format provided by VS Project Configurator. Works when: either output folder name has with no trailing "\" or folder name ends up with "\.".

#### Workaroud

1. Disable Inf2Cat under Project Preferences: *Run Inf2Cat* -> **No**
2. Configure build events under Build-Events->Post Build-Event: *Command Line* -> `"$(WindowsSdkDir)bin\$(DDKPlatform)\inf2cat.exe" /os:10_$(DDKPlatform) /driver:"$(ProjectDir)$(IntDir)$(MSBuildProjectName)"`